# How can I quickly test changes when developing a Chrome Extension using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use `npm run` to test my chrome extension, however I get expected errors saying 'chrome' is undefined.

I use their API to store user data using `chrome.storage.sync`, runtime checks `chrome.runtime.lastError`, and tab info like `chrome.tabs.query(...)`.

Right now the issue is I need to 1) `npm run build`, 2) upload / refresh the extension in the Extensions tab, and then finally take a look if the changes applied, or if there is any issues.

I have found an npm package that allows me to use storage called `chrome-storage` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-storage), but I'm assuming there is a better way to do this? I just want to make changes in my IDE and have it auto update the browser window so I see changes (which I usually get from reactjs).

Comment: have you tried using `window.chrome` ?

Comment: It says "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" for window.chrome.tabs.query(...)

Comment: .. are you sure there's a property `tabs` for the `chrome` object ? I didn't find  it in my console..

Comment: Yes positive, it works when I load it as a google extension, the problem is I don't think the console has access to it, so I was hoping there is some alternative way of testing the POST/GETS with the chrome extension API without having to build -> load extension in chrome extensions -> inspect extension, it's kind of tedious.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to make changes in my IDE and have it auto update the
>   browser window so I see changes (which I usually get from reactjs).

It seems you want a boilerplate with the "hot reload" feature supported. Check those out for example: [react-chrome-extension-boilerplate](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-chrome-extension-boilerplate), [crossbuilder](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/crossbuilder). But from my experience you mostly still need to reload the current page in the browser to see changes (depends on what kind of changes).